# Get values from json array using javascript or php

Tags: javascript, php, json

Here is my code:

```
var newval =[{"new_id":"1","new_no":"1","total":"N.A"},{"new_id":"2","new_no":"3","total":"4"},{"new_id":"2","new_no":"4","total":"5"}];
```

from this json value how to get details based on new_no value using javascript or php.

```
  function passfun(new_no)
  {
    alert(newval[0].plot_no);
  }
```

I tried like this but its working based on json array values i not getting exact values based on new_no

Comment: That's not JSON. It's just an array with objects in it.

Comment: ok. how to get values from that using particular key pair @Quentin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an array of objects in JSON format. In PHP you can use the following code:

PHP:

```
<?php
$json = '[{"new_id":"1","new_no":"1","total":"N.A"},{"new_id":"2","new_no":"3","total":"4"},{"new_id":"2","new_no":"4","total":"5"}]';

$data = json_decode($json);

function get_prop($object, $name)
{
    return $object->{$name};

}


print get_prop($data[0], 'new_no')."\n";
print get_prop($data[0], 'new_id')."\n";
```

JavaScript:

```
var newval =[{"new_id":"1","new_no":"1","total":"N.A"},
             {"new_id":"2","new_no":"3","total":"4"},
             {"new_id":"2","new_no":"4","total":"5"}];

function get_prop(obj, name)
{
    return obj[name];
}

alert(get_prop(newval[0], 'new_no'));
```

Comment: your not getting my point. If we pass one parameter(example: new_no) in a method using that i need to get other values also in that array.

Comment: alert(newval[0].new_no); this method i tried already.

Comment: @SaravananMP Ahh, I see. I'll try and let you know.

Comment: same thing repeated.

Comment: @SaravananMP Sorry, I don't understand, what you mean. The PHP code is getting property value by text name. The same for javascript.